# XML :: WebAPI :: Multiple items

Tags: c#, xml, webapi

I am developing a WebAPI that should accept an XML, created by a customer.
the XML is styled as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AcquisitionDetails>
  <Acquisition>
    <GeoCode>PHX</GeoCode>
    <OrderDate>11/25/2019 12:00:00 AM</OrderDate>
    <PartNo>4X50K14092</PartNo>
    <QtyExpected>10</QtyExpected>
    <PONumber>1990000446</PONumber>
    <Supplier>Lenovo (International) BV</Supplier>
  </Acquisition>
  <Acquisition>
    <GeoCode>PHX</GeoCode>
    <OrderDate>11/25/2019 12:00:00 AM</OrderDate>
    <PartNo>4X50K14091</PartNo>
    <QtyExpected>10</QtyExpected>
    <PONumber>1990000446</PONumber>
    <Supplier>Lenovo (International) BV</Supplier>
  </Acquisition>
</AcquisitionDetails>
```

What I am able to come up with (together with the help of some StackOverflow people that tried to answer my earlier question (now deleted);

Controller:

```
namespace ServicesTools.WebServices.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AcquisitionController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AcquisitionController> _logger;

        public AcquisitionController(ILogger<AcquisitionController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }


        [Consumes("application/xml")]
        [Produces("application/xml")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post(List<Acquisition> AcquisitionDetails)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Am Here!");

            if (AcquisitionDetails != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(AcquisitionDetails.Count());
            }


            return Ok();
        }

    }
}
```

```
    public class Acquisition
    {
        public string GeoCode { get; set; }
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string PartNo { get; set; }
        public int QtyExpected { get; set; }
        public uint PONumber { get; set; }
        public string Supplier { get; set; }
    }
```

This gets close to the solution, but there is an issue:
for this this work, I need to wrap the entire XML into extra tags (PurchaseOrder) in this case:

```
<PurchaseOrder xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServicesTools.WebServices">
    <AcquisitionDetails>
        <Acquisition>
            <GeoCode>PHX</GeoCode>
            <OrderDate>11/25/2019 12:00:00 AM</OrderDate>
            <PartNo>4X50K14092</PartNo>
            <QtyExpected>10</QtyExpected>
            <PONumber>1990000446</PONumber>
            <Supplier>Lenovo (International) BV</Supplier>
        </Acquisition>
        <Acquisition>
            <GeoCode>PHX</GeoCode>
            <OrderDate>11/25/2019 12:00:00 AM</OrderDate>
            <PartNo>4X50K14092</PartNo>
            <QtyExpected>10</QtyExpected>
            <PONumber>1990000446</PONumber>
            <Supplier>Lenovo (International) BV</Supplier>
        </Acquisition>
    </AcquisitionDetails>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

this is not what I intend; I need `AcquisitionDetails` to be the top level, and contain an array of `Acquisition`; but as soon as I try to convert the class PurchaseOrder to (for example AcquisitionDetails), the Array doesnt get filled

On request, also the Startup.cs

```
namespace ServicesTools.WebServices
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the settings of your project. What exactly serializer do you use?

Comment: Ok, `DataContractSerializer`. Need to think.

Comment: I am not forced to use that by the way, if there is a different, or more suiteable serializer, then I am all in for that..

Comment: why is something that in Powershell is a oneliner: "foreach ($y in $x.AcquisitionDetails.Acquisition) { write-host $y.GeoCode}" so hard to do in .Net Core???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve your objective, since you are using the XmlDataContractSerializer, setup your your model like the code-snippet below.

```
[CollectionDataContract(Namespace ="")]
public class AcquisitionDetails : List<Acquisition> 
{
    
    
}


[DataContract(Name = "Acquisition", Namespace ="")]
public class Acquisition
{
    [DataMember]
    public string GeoCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string OrderDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Supplier { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PartNo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int QtyExpected { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public uint PONumber { get; set; }
    
}
```

The CollectionDataContract, DataContract and DataMember  attribute are in the  `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace, so you'll need to add a using statement to reference that.

See reference's here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts

This should work.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer more than once, you just saved my sanity!
This does _exactly_ what I need it to do.

Comment: Happy to help Fimlore!